# How to pause deadlocked program and examine stack trace of each thread (VS, C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, deadlock

I've reproduced the Windows Form application [Locked Up](http://yacsharpblog.blogspot.ru/2008/07/locked-up.html) article. It is for Visual Studio 2008 but I followed it in VS2010

The follow-up article [Lock Up Unlocked](http://yacsharpblog.blogspot.ru/2008/07/lock-up-unlocked.html) tells:

> "If you run it and click the button a few times rapidly, the
>   application stops responding"

Pretty dead...

> "Then, if you pause the program and examine the stack trace of each
>   thread, you find..."

How do I pause the program and examine stack trace of each thread in Visual Studio (preferably 2010, I hope it is the same in others)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the program under the debugger. You should have a pause button on the toolbar, which will pause the program running under the debugger. If not, try using the menu: Debug > Break All.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how to distinguish there stack traces between threads

Comment: Try opening the Threads window in the debugger: Debug -> Windows -> Threads.

Comment: Also, in VS2010 you should have the "parallel stacks" window which will show you the different thread stack traces side-by-side. Very useful for debugging multithread issues.